# jquery-file-upload plugin : How to change the upload path?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, file-upload

I'm trying to work with the blueimp jquery-file-upload plugin.
Seems to be a good uploader, but the documentation is not helpful.

When I work with the downloadable demo script, all is ok. 
But, when I want to change the upload path, that doesn't work.

I've tried to change, in index.php, the action path, like this :

```
form id="fileupload" action="../uploads/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

and added the folders "files" and "thumbnails" in my "uploads" folder.

The GET call is ok, as I can see in Firebug :

```
GET http://localhost/alliance_pretests/uploads/ 200 OK -8ms
```

But when I launch the upload action, the POST answers me (still in Firebug) :

```
POST http://localhost/alliance_pretests/uploads/ 404 Not Found 44ms
```

I didn't change anything else.
What did I forget ?

Why the GET call sees the folder, but not the POST call ?

Thanks in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: how are you using this plugin ? do did you implement the server side or use Node.js version ? you need to update the backend to specify the upload directory

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The form action is not the folder where your upload folder should be. The form action is the script where the data is sent after submitting.  (see more here about form actions http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp)

Try finding a destination folder for uploads or look inside the script for that.

**Update: after downloading the library**

You should look in server/php/upload.class.php and there you have some variables with the location of the upload folder:

```
'script_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/',
'upload_dir' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']).'/files/',
'upload_url' => $this->getFullUrl().'/files/',
```

Tou should replace `/files/` with your own upload folder.

Comment: I understood your explanation, and changed my code.That works fine now. Thanks a lot. But how to declare a folder one level upper, like "../uploads" ? I've tried but it doesn't seem to work (error JSON).

Comment: How did you modify it? It should be like `'upload_url' => '../uploads/'`

Comment: It was not working because I didn't removeed $this : 'upload_url' => $this->'../uploads/'
Now it's OK.
Thanks a lot !

Comment: hey, I am working on adding this plugin to wordpress and need to upload to wp's default `uploads` folder which in my case (because I'm working in a plugin) is three directories up ... this is where `UploadHandler.php` is `wordpress/wp-content/plugins/photo-uploadr/templates/UploadHandler.php` and the uploads dir is here `wordpress/wp-content/uploads`. I've tried doing this `../../../uploads/` but it just creates a new directory (within the `templates` directory) three levels deep and puts the file there! I'm confused ... nothing I try works.

Answer (score 21):

Although the answer @mugur supplied is correct, looking at the php class supplied with the library the first parameter in the construct method is "options" and by declaring an associative array as follows:

```
$options = array('upload_dir'=>'upload/directory/of/your/choice', 'upload_url'=>'upload/directory/of/your/choice');
```

and passing it as the first parameter when instantiating the class:

```
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

Will allow you to change the upload directory every time you use the class rather than altering the source code.

Comment: You must add these options to the file where you're instantiating the class, if you're using the example then it's [index.php](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/index.php).

It'd look something like:

`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);`

`require('UploadHandler.php');`

`$options = array('upload_dir'=>'upload/directory/of/your/choice',` 

`'upload_url'=>'upload/directory/of/your/choice');`

`$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);`

Comment: What value should I give `upload_url` if I want to upload my files outside the `www` folder?

Comment: upload_url is the string returned to client browser to display uploaded image or thumbnail. If you upload outside www folder, therefore not accessible for web server to serve files to browser, the image can't be shown. You can instead redirect to some kind of confirmation message or you can copy those files also to some www folder. That's from my short experience with this package.